# How to get thumbnails of video uploaded in Youtube using Youtube Data API in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, youtube-api

I have an application in which I have manually uploaded videos using Youtube Data API.

It is working fine.

But now I want to display thumbnails of video uploaded by my users in my application.

I have tried a lot for this with `getVideoThumbnails()`, but I can not get `videoEntry` object of recently uploaded video.

**This is my code :**

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube($httpClient,$applicationkey,null,$developerkey);

$videoEntry = $yt->getVideoEntry('the0KZLEacs');

$videoThumbnails = $videoEntry->getVideoThumbnails();

  foreach($videoThumbnails as $videoThumbnail) {

    echo $videoThumbnail['time'] . ' - ' . $videoThumbnail['url'];
    echo ' height=' . $videoThumbnail['height'];
    echo ' width=' . $videoThumbnail['width'] . "\n";
  }
```

Here, the0KZLEacs is a id of uploaded video.

Have any idea?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I see that you say you have an app that uploads videos via the youtube API. Could you provide example code or links to how you got that done? I'd greatly appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/<?php echo $video_id; ?>/default.jpg
```

Where `$video_id` is the ID of your YouTube video.

Comment: Thanks man I think it will work for me.

But will it work also for recently uploaded video ?

Thanks again..